# Custom Authentication Processing Filter Location in SecurityFilterChain?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a custom implementation of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` that I need to manually insert in the Security Filter Chain. I've seen multiple tutorials, each saying to insert it before or after a different filter in the chain.

Is there a definitive answer on where this filter is supposed to be placed? Or, at least, a rule of thumb that can help figure it out?

Visual reference below:

```java
@Bean
public void SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) {

    MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter();

    http
        .addFilterBefore(filter, WhateverFilter.class);

    // rest of configuration here

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation, implementations of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` are placed between `ConcurrentSessionFilter` and `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can  define a AuthenticationProvider bean to process an authentication

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

}
```

Comment: That's already done, but not mentioned in the question since it wasn't relevant. Anyways, although this page is old the answer seems to be in section 8.3 of this documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/security-filter-chain.html

Comment: the security filter's order define in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterOrderRegistration